# Create alphabet buttons

Tags: android

I want to make buttons with the letters of alphabet and group them like this:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

So 5 per line. That means these 3 lines must be wrapped by a layout with vertical orientation, and the lines must have horizontal orientation.(note that in the code below I didn't put the 5 per line condition yet)

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlay);
    for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {        
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setText(String.valueOf((char) i));
        button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(button);
    }
```

`linlay` here has vertical orientation, so it will show my buttons one under each other:

```
a
b
c
d
..
```

How can I do this? Do I have to create a layout for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested linear layouts, as you're thinking, but a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) would probably be more appropriate.

Given that what you want is along the lines of a numeric keypad layout, just with a few more keys, perhaps [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677) or others like it might be a good source of inspiration?

Comment: Well the thing is that one is already done with .xml. What I want is to create them dynamically.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you creating a GridLayout dynamically—you may end up asking a more answerable question if you try an approach or two and see if you get stuck on a specific issue...

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Cool :) If you want to help someone else in the future, you might consider answering your own question and including the code that worked for you (I won't mind if you mark your answer as the correct one!)

Answer (score 0):

I have not done anything like this before, but by logical guess, metioned a code sample. Kindly try if it works.

```
int kStartIndex=0;
String s="",fullString="";
for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i+=5) {
  Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(i);
        kStartIndex = i;
 for(int j=0;j<5;j++) { 
        if(kStartIndex <=90)
        {       
        s = String.valueOf((char) kStartIndex );
fullString =fullString+s;
        }
    kStartIndex++;
    }
 button.setText(fullString);
        button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(button);
fullString = "";
}
```